# Print data in console log using model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to print data in with `console.log()` from within a model, but I am failing.

```
var student_read_data = new StudentModel({
    id: studnet_id
});
console.log(student_read_data);
console.log("-- --- --- -- -- -- --- ");
console.log(student_read_data);
student_read_data.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log("Your Name is : " + student_read_data.get(name));
    }
});
}
} else {
    console.log("This is a test ");
}
}
});
$(function() {
    var view = new StudentFilterView({
        el: 'form',
        model: new StudentModel()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define what StudentModel is.

```
var StudentModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
```

Then you can initialize

```
var student_read_data = new StudentModel({
  id: "student_id"
});
```

Now you can

```
console.log(student_read_data)
```